# SCSS: How to not repeat declaration in CSS file?

Tags: css, node.js, sass

So I'm using two separate graphics that use the same options:

```
#basicMob .progress {
    background: green none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

#notBasicMob .progress {
    background: green none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

How can I declare #basicMob and #notBasicMob, and have .progress affect them both? I keep trying things like:

```
#basicMob,
#notBasicMob .progress {
    background: green none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

But so far I haven't been able to find what works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an element with a `.progress` class descended from an element with either of these id's, the following pattern should work:

```
.parent {
    .child {}
}
```

so in your case:

```
#basicMob,
#notBasicMob {
     .progress {
         background: green none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

NB: If the elements with those id's also had the `.progress` class, you could use the `&` to select your elements as necessary:

```
.some-class {
   &.another-class {}
}
```

More information about these patterns can be found here: https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/

Comment: That you for this suggestion. So specific for my case, I had to remove the '&'. So, .progress but &.progress does not. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
#basicMob .progress,
#notBasicMob .progress {
    background: green none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

You need to have the selector for ".progress" before the comma as well.